# how to used objloader in three.js to load an object or image from blob link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

Hello I need Help on this.

This is my code for showing an object

but the object that I need to show is not display.

```
   var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
    loader.load('https://twportal.blob.core.windows.net/ecardbackground/scenes1.obj', function ( object ) {

        object.traverse( function ( child ) {

            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

                child.material.map = texture;

            }

        } );
```

please let me know what is my error.